# JAXB - How to marshal java object without header

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling

I'm trying to marshal a java object but I want to remove the header that Jaxb is introducing.

**Object:**

```
@XmlRootElement
public class FormElement implements Serializable {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private Integer order;
}
```

**Expected output:**

```
<element>
    <id>asd</id>
    <name>asd</name>
    <order>1</order>
</element>
```

**My output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<formElement>
  <id>asd</id>
  <name>asd</name>
  <order>1</order>
</formElement>
```

**My marshal method:**

```
public String marshal() {
        JAXBContext context;
        try {
            context = JAXBContext.newInstance(FormElement.class);
            Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            marshaller.marshal(this, stringWriter);
            return stringWriter.toString();
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
        }
        return null;
    }
```

How can I remove it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I have solved it using

`marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);`

and adding `(name = "element")` to the `@XmlRootElement` annotation.

The right method:

```
public String marshal() {
    JAXBContext context;
    try {
        context = JAXBContext.newInstance(FormElement.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.marshal(this, stringWriter);
        return stringWriter.toString();
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        String mess = "Error marshalling FormElement " + e.getMessage()
                + (e.getCause() != null ? ". " + e.getCause() : " ");
        System.out.println(mess);
    }
    return null;
}
```

And the right annotation:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "element")
```